# Need help increasing the speed of my code

Tags: python

Code:

```
    import requests
    from gtts import gTTS
    import os
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import urllib.request
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
    from reportlab.graphics import renderPM
    from tkinter import filedialog
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    tabs = ttk.Notebook(root)
    tabs.place(x=0, y=0)
    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
    tabs.add(tab1, text = "Display workouts in a list format")
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
    tabs.add(tab2, text = "images")
    tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
    tabs.add(tab3, text = "play sound")
    root["background"] = "red"
    root.geometry('400x400')
    # Save all info
    class Split():
      def __init__(self,name,programs):
        self.name = name
        self.programs = programs
    class Program_Routine():
      def __init__(self, name, workouts):
        self.name = name
        self.workouts = workouts
    class Workout():
      def __init__(self, name, exercises):
        self.name = name
        self.exercises = exercises
    class Exercise():
      def __init__(self,name,rep,set,instruction,difficulty):
        self.name = name
        self.rep = rep
        self.set = set
        self.instruction = instruction
        self.difficulty = difficulty
    def m(option,muscle):
      url = "https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/exercises"
      global response
      response = requests.get(f'{url}?{option}={muscle}',headers={'X-Api-Key': 'EYubhelGF0jRmCC4ZtZKZg==pWcZsqUXcpnwlFW7'})
      global request
      request = response.json()
      return request
    arr = ["muscle","type"]
    arr2 = ["glutes","biceps","forearms","traps","hamstrings","triceps","calves","quadriceps","abductors","lats","lower_back","middle_back","abdominals","cardio","stretching","strength"]
    variables = {}
    
    for j in range(0,len(arr2)-3):
      variables["var"+str(j)] = m(arr[0],arr2[int(j)])
    for z in range(13,16):
      variables["var"+str(z)] = m(arr[1],arr2[int(z)])
    var_holder = {}
    
    
    def fill_holder(day,body_part):
      for i in range(len(day)):
        var_holder[body_part + str(i)] = Exercise(day[i]["name"].lower(), 12,3,day[i]["instructions"],day[i]["difficulty"])
      return var_holder
    for l in range(len(variables)):
      fill_holder(variables["var"+str(l)],arr2[l])  
    def append(indices):
      x = []
      for i in range(len(var_holder)//18):
          x.append(var_holder[f'{indices}{i}'])
      return x
    forearms = Workout("Forearm Workout", append('forearms'))
    glutes = Workout("Glutes Workout", append('glutes'))
    biceps = Workout("Bicep workout",append('biceps'))
    traps = Workout("Shoulder Workout",append('traps'))
    hamstrings = Workout("Hamstring workout",append('hamstrings'))
    triceps = Workout("Tricep Workout",append("triceps"))
    calves = Workout("Calves Workout",append("calves"))
    quadriceps = Workout("Quadricep Workout",append("quadriceps"))
    abductors = Workout("Abductor Workout",append("abductors"))
    lats = Workout("Lats Workout(Upper Back)",append("lats"))
    lower_back = Workout("Lower Back Workout",append("lower_back"))
    middle_back = Workout("Middle Back Workout",append("middle_back"))
    cardio = Workout("Cardio_Routine",append("cardio"))
    stretching = Workout('''Stretching before your 
    workout [must do this everytime]''',append("stretching"))
    abdominals = Workout("Abdominal Workout",append("abdominals"))
    strength = Workout("Full Body strength Workout",append("strength"))
    
    Leg_Day = Program_Routine("Legs", [glutes,hamstrings,calves,quadriceps,abductors])
    Arm_Day = Program_Routine("Arms", [stretching,forearms,biceps,triceps])
    Shoulder_Day = Program_Routine("Shoulders", [stretching,traps])
    Back_Day = Program_Routine("Back",[stretching,lats,middle_back,lower_back])
    Full_body_Day = Program_Routine("Full_Body",[stretching,cardio,abdominals,strength])
    
    Five_day_split = Split("5 day split",[Leg_Day,Arm_Day,Shoulder_Day,Back_Day,Full_body_Day])
    
    
    
    
    
    def display(insert,tab):
      url = f'https://uk.images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=AwrIfln4XytkPt4DqAAM34lQ;_ylu=Y29sbwNpcjIEcG9zAzEEdnRpZAMEc2VjA3BpdnM-?p={insert}+gym+diagram+instructions&fr2=piv-web&type=E210GB91082G0&fr=mcafee'
      page = requests.get(url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
      holder = soup.find('img')
      if holder['alt'] == "":
        holder['alt'] = "Something"
      
      def Show_Image(tab,image,displayname):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, displayname) 
        #renderPM.drawToFile(svg2rlg(displayname), displayname+"png", fmt='PNG')
        global img
        img = Image.open(displayname)
        img = img.resize((250, 250))
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        lbl = tk.Label(tab,image=img)
        lbl.grid(row=1,column=0)
        os.remove(displayname)
      Show_Image(tab,holder['data-src'],holder['alt'])
    
    
    pop_up_frame = tk.Frame(tab1,bg="black",highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=2)
    pop_up_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    def show(program,y):
      inside_frame = tk.Frame(tab1,bg="black",highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=2)
      inside_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
      inside_frame.propagate(False)
      inside_frame.config(width=400,height=400)
      def quit_first_inside_frame():
        inside_frame.destroy()
      
      close_first_inside_frame_button = tk.Button(inside_frame,text="Close",bg="red",command=quit_first_inside_frame)
      close_first_inside_frame_button.grid(row=1,column=len(program.workouts))
      gym = tk.StringVar()
      def clicked(value):
        global pop_up_frame
        pop_up_frame = tk.Frame(tab1,bg="black",highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=2)
        pop_up_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        pop_up_frame.propagate(False)
        pop_up_frame.config(width=400,height=400)
        def quit_second_inside_frame():
          pop_up_frame.destroy()
        close_second_inside_frame_button = tk.Button(pop_up_frame,text="Close",bg="red",command=quit_second_inside_frame)
        close_second_inside_frame_button.grid(row=0,column=len(program.workouts))
        name = options.index(value)
        instruct = instructions[name]
        diff = difficulty[name]
        picture = value
        if len(picture.split()) > 1:
          picture = picture.split()
          picture = '+'.join(picture)
        try:
          display(picture,pop_up_frame)
          tk.Label(pop_up_frame,text=f'A picture showing {value}:').grid(row=0,column=0)
        except:
          tk.Label(pop_up_frame,text="Change name of this exercise, url retrieval isn't working in this format",wraplength=100).grid(row=1,column=0)
        label.config(text = instruct,wraplength = 500)
        label2.config(text = diff.upper(), wraplength = 600)
        label2.grid(row=2, column=0)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)
      options = []
      instructions = []
      difficulty = []
      # Upload info to arrays in order to fill out radiobuttons
      for j in range(len(program.workouts)):
        for i in range(len(program.workouts[j].exercises)):
          instructions.append(program.workouts[j].exercises[i].instruction)
          difficulty.append(program.workouts[j].exercises[i].difficulty)  
          options.append(program.workouts[j].exercises[i].name)      
        for i in range(len(program.workouts[j].exercises)):
          Header = tk.Label(inside_frame,text = program.workouts[j].name,fg="blue")
          Header.grid(row=0,column=j)
          Radio = tk.Radiobutton(inside_frame,
                                 text="",
                                 variable=gym,
                                 value=program.workouts[j].exercises[i].name,
                                 command=lambda: clicked(gym.get()))
          Radio.config(text = program.workouts[j].exercises[i].name,fg="green")
          Radio.grid(row=i+2, column=j)
      label = tk.Label(tab2 , text = "")
      label.grid(row=0, column=0)
      label2 = tk.Label(tab2 , text = "")
      label2.grid(row=2, column=0)
    
    
    gym = tk.StringVar()
    def pressed(value):
      show(Five_day_split.programs[int(value)],0)
      
    for i in range(len(Five_day_split.programs)):
      Front = tk.Radiobutton(tab1,text=Five_day_split.programs[i].name,variable=gym,value=i,
                                 command=lambda: pressed(gym.get()))
      Front.grid(row=1+i, column=0)
    
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(tab3)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=1)
    myList = tk.Listbox(tab3, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    for line in range(1,101):
      myList.insert("end", "This is line number "+str(line))
    myList.grid(row=0,column=0)
    scrollbar.config(command=myList.yview)
    
    
    tk.mainloop()
```

My code works fine. I was just wondering when I click the radiobutton whether it's possible for it to scrape for the images faster and not have the latency between the click and the image displaying be quite so pronounced. My code works completely. Just wondering about optimization of speed and processing and wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Which lines of the code are taking the most time? You should identify the bottlenecks yourself and then ask specific questions about improving them.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not completely sure. But I think it's that whole  middle display function. Whenever I click a radiobutton, the program takes quite some times to load the picture. I was wondering about getting around to sorting out that clunky function into classes and behaviours at some points. Do you think that would help? Also sorry to sound ignorant, but what's a "bottleneck"?

Comment: try writing the images to a local cache and if they are not there, go get them and then put them in the cache. Then check the cache first for the images and just use them if they are there.

Comment: It's scraping the images from google images using beautiful soup. You're saying I should scrape the images, save them locally then use them?